# Looping a python program with if statments

Tags: python, loops, encryption

I am writing a python program that will encrypt and decrypt a file. All the formulas in my code should work just fine but I'm having trouble with the actual loop. I want to present the user with the option to either encrypt, decrypt, or exit. Once they make their selection and go through the process I would like the program to automatically ask them the same question over again until they choose to exit the program.

I appreciate any advice of what I could fix or may be doing wrong.

Edit: To clarify, my code right now will continue to loop only what the user initially picks. It does not give them the option to pick encrypt or decrypt continuously until they exit.

Below is the main function in charge of the loop:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Vigenere-cipher Encryption/Decryption Program\n")
    validStrings = ['e', 'd', 'x']
    userInput = input("Would you like to (e)ncrypt a file, (d)ecrypt a file, or e(x)it (enter e, d, or x)? ")
    while userInput not in validStrings:
        userInput = input("Sorry, that's an invalid choice. Please enter only e, d, or x: ")

    if userInput == 'e':
        while True:
            path = input("Enter the text-file name to encrypt: ")
            if osp.exists(path):
                encrypt(path)
            else:
                print("Sorry the file", path, "does NOT exist -- please try again!") 

    elif userInput == 'd':
        path = input("Enter the text-file name to decrypt: ")
        if osp.exists(path):
            fileName,fileExtension = osp.split(path)
            fileName = fileName+".txt"
            if osp.exists(fileName):
                print("WARNING: The file '%s' already exists!" %fileName)

                ch = input("Is it okay to wipe it out (y/n)? ")
                if ch == 'n':
                    fileName = input("Enter the file name text that should be used (.txt extension will automatically be added) ")
                    fileName = fileName + ".txt"
                elif ch == 'y':
                    pass
            decrypt(path, fileName)

    elif userInput == 'x':
        print("Program Complete!")
        return
```

Comment: `"Once they make their selection and go through the process I would like the program to automatically ask them the same question over again until they choose to exit the program."` What do you mean by "selection" here? The `"e,d,x"` or the `"enter a filename"`?

Comment: I am referring to the e, d, or x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose the option in (e)ncrypt in your program, you enter a `while` loop whose exit condition is always true. In this loop, even if you enter a valid file name, the loop will go on. You could solve it by using a `break` statement once a valid file name got entered like

```
if userInput == 'e':
    while True:
        path = input("Enter the text-file name to encrypt: ")
        if osp.exists(path):
             encrypt(path)
             print("Yeah!,1")
             break
        else:
            print("Sorry the file", path, "does NOT exist -- please try again!")
```

In the (d)ecrypt part, if the user enters the name of a pre-existing file, an option to overwrite is provided. But if the user enters the name of a pre-existing file again, you may display the message alerting the user again. You can do this by placing it in a loop in which `break` statement is executed if user gives the go-ahead to overwrite the file like

```
elif userInput == 'd':
    path = input("Enter the text-file name to decrypt: ")
    if osp.exists(path):
        fileName,fileExtension = osp.split(path)
        fileName = fileName+".txt"
        print("Filename: ", fileName, "path: ", path)

        while osp.exists(fileName):
            print("WARNING: The file '%s' already exists!" %fileName)

            ch = input("Is it okay to wipe it out (y/n)? ")
            if ch == 'n':
                fileName = input("Enter the file name text that should be used (.txt extension will automatically be added) ")
                fileName = fileName + ".txt"
            elif ch == 'y':
                break 
        decrypt(path, fileName)
```

You could put the whole menu-driven part in a loop like

```
while True:
    userInput = input("Would you like to (e)ncrypt a file, (d)ecrypt a file, or e(x)it (enter e, d, or x)? ")
    while userInput not in validStrings:
        userInput = input("Sorry, that's an invalid choice. Please enter only e, d, or x: ")

    if userInput == 'e':
        while True:
            path = input("Enter the text-file name to encrypt: ")
            if osp.exists(path):
                 encrypt(path)
                 break
            else:
                print("Sorry the file", path, "does NOT exist -- please try again!") 

    elif userInput == 'd':
        path = input("Enter the text-file name to decrypt: ")
        if osp.exists(path):
            fileName,fileExtension = osp.split(path)
            fileName = fileName+".txt"
            print("Filename: ", fileName, "path: ", path)
            while osp.exists(fileName):
                print("WARNING: The file '%s' already exists!" %fileName)

                ch = input("Is it okay to wipe it out (y/n)? ")
                if ch == 'n':
                    fileName = input("Enter the file name text that should be used (.txt extension will automatically be added) ")
                    fileName = fileName + ".txt"
                elif ch == 'y':
                    break 
            decrypt(path, fileName)

    elif userInput == 'x':
        print("Program Complete!")
        return
```

While you split the file name to its name and extension, use

```
fileName, fileExtension = osp.splitext(path)
```

instead of

```
fileName,fileExtension = osp.split(path)
```

if `path` stores just the name of the file.

If `path` is an absolute path or something you could do

```
path,fullFileName = osp.split(path)
fileName, fileExtension = osp.splitext(fullFileName)
```

Read about `splitext()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like you need to make a bit of modifications while user makes their choice. Here, I modified your code snippet a bit just take a look :

```
def main():
print("Welcome to the Vigenere-cipher Encryption/Decryption Program\n")
validStrings = ['e', 'd', 'x']
while True :
    userInput = input("Would you like to (e)ncrypt a file, (d)ecrypt a file, or e(x)it (enter e, d, or x)? ")
    if(userInput not in validStrings)
        userInput = input("Sorry, that's an invalid choice. Please enter only e, d, or x: ")
    elif : 
        if userInput == 'e':
            while True:
                path = input("Enter the text-file name to encrypt: ")
                if osp.exists(path):
                    encrypt(path)
                else:
                    print("Sorry the file", path, "does NOT exist -- please try again!")
            continue
        elif userInput == 'd':
            path = input("Enter the text-file name to decrypt: ")
            if osp.exists(path):
                fileName,fileExtension = osp.split(path)
                fileName = fileName+".txt"
                if osp.exists(fileName):
                    print("WARNING: The file '%s' already exists!" %fileName)

                    ch = input("Is it okay to wipe it out (y/n)? ")
                    if ch == 'n':
                        fileName = input("Enter the file name text that should be used (.txt extension will automatically be added) ")
                        fileName = fileName + ".txt"
                    elif ch == 'y':
                        pass
                decrypt(path, fileName)
            continue
        elif userInput == 'x':
            break
    print("Program Complete!")
    return
```

The only change made here is that until user provides 'x' as input, while loop will not allow user to take any other actions.

Let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: I have tried adding this code but when I run the program it is still not working. If i pick e to encrypt, it will ask me for the file, then my keyword, after that it successfully creates the new file. The next prompt is to enter another file and that is the continuously loop it goes through.

Comment: @Alex : Just made modifications to current code snippet. Can you please check and confirm.

Comment: This produces UnboundLocalError: local variable 'userInput' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Alex : Can you confirm now. I checked on my machine.